# Apache POI Performance of Excel vs CSV

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I'm looking to use Apache POI for data driven tests. Performance wise, is it faster using one file format over the other? CSV or Excel?

Comment: An Excel sheet is way more complex than a simple CSV file. But it depends of your needs.

Comment: Yes, CSV is much more lightweight, just your data and delimiters. You wouldn't even need POI for this, but some more lightweight library.